# Customizing weekend using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd DatePicker for date range purposes.

How can I style the days that are sundays using css. Help will be appreciated

edit:

I am getting this blue background between start , range and the end. I want that to be continous. Also there is gap between selected rows, I want it to be purple itself. But here I see white color between selected rows

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import en_GB from "antd/lib/locale-provider/en_GB";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/en-gb";
moment.locale("en-gb");

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br />
      <ConfigProvider locale={en_GB}>
        <RangePicker />
      </ConfigProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-6gmz85?file=/src/App.js:0-511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nth-child selector to isolate the sunday column and style as desired.

```
.ant-picker-content tr td:nth-child(7) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

To remove the padding just change css to:

```
.ant-picker-cell {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, There is a minor edit, It would be great if you take a look at it as well

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the rendered cells by providing a `dateRender` function to `RangePicker`.
The `0` is for Sunday, meaning that the style will only be applied to Sundays ([Moment.js Doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/))

```js
<RangePicker
  dateRender = {(current) => {
    const style = {};
    if (current.day() === 0) {
      style.border = "1px solid #3390FF";
    }
    return (
      <div className="ant-calendar-date" style={style}>
        {current.date()}
      </div>
    ); 
  }}
/>
```

To fix the padding and the coloring of the range you can try

```css
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start
.ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background-color: green !important;
}


.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-end
.ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background-color: green !important;
}


.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-today
.ant-picker-cell-inner::before {
  border-color: green !important;
}


.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-start-single)::before,
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-in-range::before,
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-end:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-end-single)::before,
.ant-picker-time-panel-column
> li.ant-picker-time-panel-cell-selected
.ant-picker-time-panel-cell-inner {
  background: purple !important;
}

.ant-btn-primary {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, There is a minor edit, It would be great if you take a look at it as well